# Central Limit Theorem and understanding mean for a single object

Tags: probability, statistics

The IQ of actuarial science majors is assumed to be normally distributed with mean 112 and standard deviation of 14. In a class of 19 students, find the probability that the mean IQ of all 19 students is greater than 120.

I know this question is based of the CLT, but I don't know what to change when everyone in the group has to be above a certain mean. Shouldn't the mean just be a group average?

Comment: You don't need the CLT here. All you have to do is to find the distribution of the mean IQ. 
Hint : it's normally distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{19}$ are i.i.d random variables, what it the probability that

$$ \min(X_i)\geq 120 $$
? Obviously, it is given by:
$$ \mathbb{P}[X_1 \geq 120]^{19}.$$
Since $e^{-x^2/2}$ is a fixed point of the Fourier transform, the arithmetic mean of $n$ i.i.d normally distributed $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables is still a normal variable with the same mean and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Comment: He's asking about the mean, not the min.

Comment: @Augustin: I read it the wrong way, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, \ldots, X_{19}$ are the 19 students you sample from the class, then you can assume they're iid with distribution $N(112, 14)$ as stated in the problem. Then write $\bar{X} = (X_1 + \ldots + X_{19})/19$ for the sample mean you're dealing with.

Just from rules for means and variances of sums of independent random variables, you know that
$$ \mathbb{E} \bar{X} = \mathbb{E} X_1 = 112 \quad \textrm{and} \quad SD(\bar{X}) = \frac{SD(X_1)}{\sqrt{19}} = \frac{14}{\sqrt{19}}$$

As Augustin mentioned, note that nothing in the above relies on the Central Limit Theorem. The last fact you need is that sums of Normal random variables are still Normal (still, not relying on the CLT), so all in all you know that

$$ \bar{X} \sim N(112, 14/\sqrt{19})$$

That should help you find the answer.